# EditText is display old style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design, material-ui

I use EditText which display old style of EditText. It shows the bottom line below EditText with Corners.

[image]

I want material type EditText. that is only line comes bottom  of EditText.

[image]

EDIT:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml file, i didn't define theme for Activity, only give theme to application.

Comment: What's your Target API? You can set the theme manually for your whole app in the manifest. Try that and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Can you post the AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml from each values-xx folder.

Answer (score 0):

use AppCompatActivity. So for example, your MainActivity would look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ....
    ....
}
```

To use the AppCompatActivity, make sure you have the Google Support Library downloaded (you can check this in your Tools -> Android -> SDK manager). Then just include the gradle dependency in your app's gradle.build file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23:3.0'
```

Comment: Support Library is great. I have also wrapped my Edit Text boxes with android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.